# Перевод с карты на банковский счет на Unity

Tags: unity3d, api, платежи

Я разрабатываю сложный маркетплейс для ресторанов и мне нужно сделать безналичный расчет. Необходимо чтобы при оплате заказа деньги снимались у покупателя и отправлялись ресторану. Я очень много искал нужное APi, но везде комиссия была слишком большой (2-3% за перевод). Как мне реализовать это с минимальной комиссией и каким API?

Comment: 2% - это вроде бы вполне себе средняя комиссия за процессинг.

Comment: Я беру процент с заказов в ресторане которые происходят только через мое приложение, если я буду брать 3 % а это API 2.5% то это не очень

Comment: 5.5% - это тоже не очень много за услуги привлечения клиентов, имхо.

Comment: Я понимаю, но мне это -50% прибыли, ведь + скидка пользователю 1-2% если он через мое приложение берет по этому хотелось бы найти наимение процентно затратную APi, вот о Dwolla почитал, выглядит интересно, есть у кого опыт?. И я так понял самому API подобное создать крайне трудно т.к много бюрократии

Comment: Вы поймите, что деньги не по щелчку пальца из одного места в другое прилетают. API - это просто инструмент общения между вами и конкретным сервисом, эти сервисы берут свой % не только за "API и бюрократию".

Comment: Что-то фразы "заказы происходят только через мое приложение" и " скидка пользователю 1-2% если он через мое приложение берет" не очень между собой стыкуются. :)

Comment: Эти фразы значат что я с заказов через мое приложение от общей суммы беру к примеру 4 %, 2 себе, 2 скидка пользователю чтобы стимулировать заказывать через приложение

Comment: Я понимаю что эти Api берут свои средства не просто так и по этому прошу у тех кто знает совета в реализации с помощью надежного Api с самым низким процентом

Comment: Вообще не совсем ясно, как вы собрались конкурировать "яндекс едой", к примеру. Да и не совсем ясно, что в метках делает юнити. Лучше уж тогда спросить в вопросе "а у какого сервиса для перевода денег наименьшая комиссия" или что-то в таком духе.

Comment: Я не вдавался в суть приложения и о том как оно будет работать о том зачем оно о том почему оно лучше аналогов и т.д и т.п потомучто это не имеет значения, я обобщил все назвав "Сложный маркетплейс" т.к это лучше всего подходит для понимания задачи. А unity  указано потомучто он используется для разработки (Просто мне показалось это лучший способ реализации Ar элементов) и возможно у кого-то есть опыт работы не только с платежами но и именно под юнити